# Using "with open() as file" method, how to write more than once?

Tags: python, file, with-statement, file-writing

Usually to write a file, I would do the following:

```
the_file = open("somefile.txt","wb")
the_file.write("telperion")
```

but for some reason, iPython (Jupyter) is NOT writing the files.  It's pretty weird, but the only way I could get it to work is if I write it this way:

```
with open('somefile.txt', "wb") as the_file:
    the_file.write("durin's day\n")

with open('somefile.txt', "wb") as the_file:
    the_file.write("legolas\n")
```

But obviously it's going to recreate the file object and rewrite it.

Why does the code in the first block not work? How could I make the second block work?

Comment: Opening a file in `"w"` mode removes all the data in the file if it exists.

Comment: Try: `the_file = open("somefile.txt", "wb", buffering=False)`.

Comment: Lets go back to your original write. Your writes are buffered until you've either written a block of data or you close the file. So you may not see the data on disk yet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `w` flag means "open for writing and truncate the file"; you'd probably want to open the file with the `a` flag which means "open the file for appending".

Also, it seems that you're using Python 2. You shouldn't be using the `b` flag, except in case when you're writing binary as opposed to plain text content. In Python 3 your code would produce an error.

Thus:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write("durin's day\n")

with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write("legolas\n")
```

---

As for the input not showing in the file using the `filehandle = open('file', 'w')`, it is because the file output is buffered - only a bigger chunk is written at a time. To ensure that the file is flushed at the end of a cell, you can use `filehandle.flush()` as the last statement.

Comment: I guess the part that's confusing for me is that I'm passing this file object around to different functions so I'm declaring it as a variable.  If I create the file w/ `var = open("file","w")` then how can I append to that variable later?

Comment: @O.rka: About the buffering in the file: the `with` statement creates a context manager that takes care of calling `the_file.close()` at the end and thereby flushing the file to disk. If you quit your Jupyter-process, the files should appear.